# Blender Python Script: Place/Connect Vertices by Global Co-ordinance

Tags: python, blender, vertices, plane

To extrude vertices, in editmode, you can simply Ctr+RMB and Blender automatically detects the mouse position and places a new connected vertex at that position.

I don't understand why I can't set the mouse position and then use the same function in the info window like this:

`bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
 bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = (1,1,1)
 bpy.ops.mesh.dupli_extrude_cursor(rotate_source=True)`

When I run that, I get the following error:

`RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.mesh.dupli_extrude_cursor.poll() expected a view3d region & editmesh`

I need it this way because the format of my object is in global co ordinance and I want to avoid interacting with the low-level functions for creating meshes since this is a script for high-level software.

EDIT>>>>

I attempted this with an operator:

```
import bpy


class MyExtrude(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.myextrude"
    bl_label = "Extrude Operator"



    def invoke(self, context, event):
        bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = (1,1,1)
        bpy.ops.mesh.dupli_extrude_cursor(rotate_source=True)
        return {'FINISHED'}


#weird workaround
classes = (MyExtrude,

          )

register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


bpy.ops.wm.myextrude('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

However it returns the same error:

`RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.mesh.dupli_extrude_cursor.poll() expected a view3d region & editmesh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an operator performs its task, it receives a context property telling it things like selected objects and which 3Dview it is working in. When you run a script in the text editor, the active viewport will be the text editor where 3d modeling operators cannot function.

It is possible to [override the context](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context) being [sent to an operator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15118/935), which allows us to run a script that works in the 3dviewport. Also note that the object needs to be [in edit mode](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.mode_set).

You could also consider defining an [operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html) and [calling other operators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49410/935) from within. When your operator is started from within the 3dview, whether that is from searching for it, attaching it to a shortcut or adding a button in a panel, it will have the correct context to pass onto the other operators.

Comment: I tried invoking it from an operator but am still getting `expected a view3d region & editmesh`